# How to change style of custom spinner in android

Tags: android, android-spinner

my view is as like this,
I am Using Custom adapter for spinner

I have design my spinner from this link 
http://rimpv.blogspot.in/2013/05/bind-spinner-dropdown-in-android.html

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            TextView v = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
            v.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            v.setText(data.get(position).name);
            return v;
        }
```

[image]

but i want to show as like this [image]

how to do this in Custom spinner ? thanks in advance for help

Comment: can you show how you are setting adapter for your spinner.

Comment: http://rimpv.blogspot.in/2013/05/bind-spinner-dropdown-in-android.html

Comment: than please share how can i do these i have same senario..

Comment: I don't find proper answer for this , that's y i do't accept any answer

Answer (score 2):

### EDIT 3

This examples are just from scratch, got no IDE to test it now.

If you don´t need a custom adapter, you can work with standard ArrayAdapter. Then set the dropDownViewResource for Your adapter.

```
public class Main extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.setContentView(R.layout.main);
    Spinner s = (Spinner) this.findViewById(R.id.spinner);

    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    list.add("Germany");
    list.add("USA");
    list.add("Nairobi");
    list.add("Japan");

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

    s.setAdapter(adapter);

    s.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent,
            View view, int pos, long id) {

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "CLICKED:"+parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView parent) {
          // Do nothing.
        }
    });
}
```

But if You need a customAdapter, then there is no other than build Your own spinner item layout:

Build Your main.xml

```
   <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:orientation="vertical"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >
   <Spinner 
      android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
      android:id="@+id/example_spinner" 
      android:layout_width="match_parent" 
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"  > 
   </Spinner>
  </LinearLayout>
```

Build Your Spinner item xml:
spinner_item.xml:

```
    <LinearLayout 
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:id="@+id/spinner_item_linear_layout" 
       android:layout_width="match_parent" 
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:orientation=”vertical”>


    <TextView        
      android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
      android:layout_height="wrap_content "
      android:id="@+id/spinner_textView" >        
    </TextView>

    <RadioButton
      android:layout_width=”wrap_content”
      android:layout_height=”wrap_content”
      android:id=”@+id/spinner_radio_button” >
   </RadioButton>

 </LinearLayout>
```

Define a string array with some input, create your custom adapter and set the adapter to your spinner.

```
    public class CustomSpinnerExample extends Activity {


  String []countries ={"Germany","USA","Nairobi","Japan"};

    @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    Spinner mySpinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.example_spinner);
    mySpinner.setAdapter(new CustomAdapter(this, R.layout.spinner_item, countries));
   }


    public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>
   {

        public CustomAdapter(Context context, int resourceId,
                    String[] objects) {
              super(context, resourceId, objects);
              // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        }
        @Override
     public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView,ViewGroup parent) {
        return getCustomView(position, convertView, parent);
     }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        return getCustomView(position, convertView, parent);
    }

    public View getCustomView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        LayoutInflater inflater=getLayoutInflater();
        View row=inflater.inflate(R.layout.spinner_item, parent, false);
        TextView label=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.spinner_textView);
         label.setText(countries[position]);


        RadioButton radioButton    =(RadioButton)row.findViewById(R.id.spinner_radio_button);
       radioButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

   public void onClick(View v){

Toast.makeText(CustomAdapter.this,”CLICKED:”+label.getText(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

  }
    });

        return row;
        }

   }
}
```

Comment: i have made my code by using this , please help me by using this 
http://rimpv.blogspot.in/2013/05/bind-spinner-dropdown-in-android.html

Comment: see my edit, if You used the example that you posted, you have to set the dropDownViewResource....

Comment: yes, now look again edit2...I am not able to test it for now, have to wait till this evening if the edit2 does not work

Comment: so ,now finally, here is another example. I think you have to let loose from your example and start a new one. This all is very basic, there are so much things to learn about spinners and adapters. Take this example as a start and go on reading everything You find about it.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a new "doubleline_spinner.xml" with source code

```
<CheckedTextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@android:id/text1"
style="?android:attr/spinnerDropDownItemStyle"
android:singleLine="false"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:ellipsize="none" 
android:textSize="15dp"

/>
```

And add that into your spinner

```
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> PolarityAAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
        R.array.polarity_arrays,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        PolarityAAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.doubleline_spinner);
        PolarityAspinner.setAdapter(PolarityAAdapter);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look to this a simple tutorial like [this](http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/basic-spinner-design). But I'm really sure you don't want to do this.

So take a look on [How to make a custom adapter with layout](http://www.survivingwithandroid.com/2012/10/android-listview-custom-adapter-and.html), tutorial is for listView but it's the same operation for spinner.

You can create your own layout that contain a `TextView` and a `CheckBox` like that :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android=”http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android&#8221;
android:id=”@+id/linearLayout1″
android:layout_width=”fill_parent”
android:layout_height=”fill_parent” >

<CheckBox
android:id=”@+DropDownList/checkbox”
android:layout_width=”wrap_content”
android:layout_height=”wrap_content” />

<TextView
android:id=”@+DropDownList/SelectOption”
android:layout_width=”wrap_content”
android:layout_height=”wrap_content” />

</LinearLayout>
```

and in your function :

```
@Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return R.layout.YourLayout;
    }
```

Comment: both link does not help me

Comment: The second link have the method: public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){}, it's the same method in the adapter in your code, in this function you can do what you want for each row of your spinner.

Just change your method : 
    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item;
      }
To return your personnal custom layout

Comment: i have seen that, but i need choose option , in your link does not show me choose option

Comment: With a custom adapter you can make what you want in each row

Answer (score 0):

[Look at this tutorial](http://easyandroidtutorials.blogspot.com/2012/05/custom-spinner-in-android.html)

You can change background image of spinner :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
    <Spinner
    android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
    android:id="@+id/spinner1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:prompt="@string/select">
    </Spinner>
</LinearLayout>
```

by adding :

`android:src="@drawable/your_image"`

to your spinner.So it will looks like :

```
<Spinner
android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
android:id="@+id/spinner1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:src="@drawable/your_image"
android:prompt="@string/select">
</Spinner>
```

Comment: i do not want to add image

Comment: if you don't want to use image , try this tutorial : http://vimaltuts.com/android-tutorial-for-beginners/android-spinner-control-example

Comment: i have try this already this is not working, did u read my question properly ?

Answer (score 0):

this is getDropDownView

```
@Override
public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    if (convertView == null)
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, null, true);

    CheckedTextView text = (CheckedTextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text1);

    text.setText("TEXT");

    return convertView;
}
```

And add this after creating the adapter

```
myAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
```