# Adapter has no effect on spinner

Tags: android, spinner, android-arrayadapter, android-appcompat

### Making spinner with custom dropdown list

I want to make a Spinner in android which will have the following dropdown list style:

[image]

My onCreate method does

```
 ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
                this, R.array.day, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
```

and

```
setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item)
```

to make the previous image's spinner dropdown list.

```
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

       Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);

        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
                this, R.array.day, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);

        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

    }
```

I followed the instructions from this [site](http://www.tuicool.com/articles/emaeme)  .
But I don't get the same dropdown list. The setDropDownViewResource and the adapter have no effect.

[image]

The only difference i find with the instructions is that the example's style is  "android:Theme.Light", while my theme style is  **Theme.AppCompat.Light**.
So, i wonder if the **AppCompat** is the problem.

Comment: I dont see the difference between the two screenshots except for the theme change. Why are you saying that adapter has no effect?

Comment: the 1st image is actually screenshot of `dialog` with single choice option, the second image is the `spinner` image with drop down layout set to the `adpater`

Comment: There are not green radio buttons and the dropdown list is not shown as dialog with title as in the example.

Comment: Yes it seems like a dialog but if you see this link http://www.tuicool.com/articles/emaeme, you will see that spinner is used.

Comment: Check this one : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16694786/how-to-customize-a-spinner-in-android or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16587181/how-to-change-style-of-custom-spinner-in-android

Answer (score 0):

try this to solve your issue

**xml:**

```
<Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner1"
        android:layout_width="275dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
        style="@android:style/Widget.Spinner"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp" />
```

**code:**

```
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.day, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);


adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.select_dialog_singlechoie);
spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```